# AWS S3 mounted on Ubuntu 16.04 Ec2 is very very slow

Tags: amazon-web-services, ubuntu-16.04, s3fs

I have an AWS S3 bucket mounted on an EC2 instance ubuntu 16.04. I installed S3FS via the `apt install s3fs -y` command and the version is 1.79.

Problem:
I noticed that copying files directly into the S3FS volume takes a lot of time. For example, last night to copy about 49M of files into the volume it took at least 20 minutes.

To test, my command was:

```
sudo s3fs -o allow_other, use_cache = /tmp/bucket [bucket name] /backup/test123/
```

I did research on slowness, and found several answers, but none spoke of a situation similar to mine.

Do you have any solutions?

Comment: Is 49M = 49.000.000?

Comment: How long does it take if you use S3 the way it's meant to be used - i.e. with something like `aws s3 cp /tmp/bucket bucketname`?

Comment: I will try it, Thanks for sharing!

Comment: 49 million files or 49 MB?

Comment: 49 mega bytes. its about 100 files.

Comment: Newer versions of s3fs has several optimizations.  Could you try 1.86?